# RequestSizeLimitAttribute: HTTP 500 instead of 413 in ASP.NET Core 2.1.401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have `[RequestSizeLimit]` on my API controller, and it *kinda* works as expected: requests bigger than specified limit are rejected.

```
    [HttpPut]
    [RequestSizeLimit(120_000_000)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(IFormCollection form)
    {
       ...
    }
```

The problem is, an exception is thrown:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStarting()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

So HTTP 500 is returned, but I would expect 413 or 400. And I don't expect an exception, since this is a perfectly normal situation.

Could not find any documentation on this. What is the right way to return 413 for requests that are too big?

Comment: Am I the only one getting *no response at all* from Kestrel when the request is too large? The browser shows no response code and there's a Network Error exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kestrel responds with a 413 Payload Too Large response, but HttpSys responds with a generic 500 Internal Server Error response. I assume you use the second one. In this case you can implement Exception handling middelware to handle this case:

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is BadHttpRequestException badRequestException && badRequestException.Message == "Request body too large.")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge;
        }
    }
}
```

And register it in Configure in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
    ...
}
```

As alternative you can also use [Exception filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exception-filters)

Comment: I use Kestrel (as the stack trace shows). The app runs on Linux using MS docker image.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn, hm, then it can be linux specific. Anyway, suggested solution should help.

Comment: It is not Linux-specific, same thing happens on windows. Your solution works though, thanks!

Comment: Filed an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2909

Comment: The check on text will not work in this middleware as it is not an BadHttpRequestException, it is an IOException, see the code on github, also the text is  $"The request's Content-Length {contentLength.Value} is larger than the request body size limit {_maxSize.Value}.");

Comment: Somewhy if I can debug into `InvokeAsync(` method, but if I send request with too big body, I don't get into `catch{}` block, as if everything was fine, even though I see `BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large` exception in logs and Firefox gets no response and shows empty page.

Comment: Strange, constructor of controller is executed, then appears `BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large` exception in logs, then in debugger I see, that `try{}` block is completed, as if everything was fine, don't get into `catch{}` block and completes execution of method `InvokeAsync()`. Then browser gets empty response.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same behavior while running in debug in Visual Studio. I discovered that the `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` causes it. I noticed `fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` in the server logs above the `BadHttpRequestException` exception.

Removing this from my `Startup.cs` gives 413 responses as expected.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Now the server logs show `fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Alex Riabov's answer, it is now possible to catch the actual internal error code thrown without parsing the text.

So the updated part of the exception handler is:

```cs
private static void HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    if (exception is BadHttpRequestException badRequestException && badRequestException.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status413PayloadTooLarge)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = badRequestException.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what runtime does it work? Tried in .Net Core 3.1, this method wasn't called.