# ASP.NET Core Web API - handle HTTP 413 (Payload too large) in middleware/ exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have existing web service to upload large content. Clients (WPF apps) has not applied any size limit.

As a quick fix, I have applied `RequestSizeLimit` in required services. Services are working fine and returns 413 if request payload size limit is exceeded, but WPF application is not handling the 413 Http status (instead displays a generic message 'Internal server error').

I want to handle 413 http status code in the Web API and respond to client as Http 400 status code along with meaningful description (http 400 is handled in the WPF application. Therefore, WPF application update is not required)

I tried to handle this situation by middleware, but middleware is not the place to capture exceptions.

I also tried to handle ExceptionHandler in Startup.cs `UseExceptionHandler`. When I am trying to do `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(message)`, nothing is happening to final response

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
 string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(_resp);
 context.Response.ContentLength = json.Length;
 await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
```

I need your assistance to handle Http status 413 and respond back with http status 400.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RequestSizeLimitAttribute: HTTP 500 instead of 413 in ASP.NET Core 2.1.401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243903/requestsizelimitattribute-http-500-instead-of-413-in-asp-net-core-2-1-401)

Comment: @viveknuna in my case web service is returning 413, but I want it re-format to 400 with custom message

Comment: I found the culprit. There is custom logging middleware after Exception handler. When status code 413 is captured in Exception handler, I was facing issue "cannot access closed stream" while writing in HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(""). 
In Logging middleware I added try/catch block, so that ResponseBody stream is writable in Exception handler. and it works.

Comment: great, you can add this as answer, so that it can help others as well.